# Ubuntu doesn't load after installing Bubmblebee - Lenovo Thinkpad e520

Tags: lenovo, bumblebee

I followed this link https://sagark.org/optimal-ubuntu-graphics-setup-for-thinkpads/ to install bumblebee. After getting it, I restarted my system.

But after BIOS I cannot continue to the system, but get stuck in a kind of console from Bumblebee/ Lenovo telling me:

> The system is running in low-graphics mode
>
> > Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

After hitting "Ok" I get to a windows asking me, which of the following I want to do:

> 1. Try running with default graphical mode
> 2. Reconfigure graphics
>
>    > 2.1 Use default config
>    >     2.2 Use backed-up config
> 3. Troubleshoot this error
>
>    > 3.1 Review the xserver log file
>    >     3.2 Review the startup errors
>    >     3.3 Edit config file
> 4. Exit to console login.

Things done under 1&2 do not help me.
Having a look at the xaerver log file, I can see the following error:

```
(==) default setting
(EE) error
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", time,,
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Undefined screen "nvidia"rerenced by ServerLayout "layout".
(EE) Problem pasing the config file
(EE) Error parsing the config file
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found (EE)
```

So now I cannot continue to the OS to even use the terminal to change, delete the files or uninstall bumblebee. Which was the overall idea how to solve that problem, as far as my research took me.

Now my question is, how can I solve this up to the point where I can access the Ubuntu terminal in order to uninstall it.

PS: sorry for the bad menu, but I cannot write it better on a mobile device :-(

Thanks for any help though!